# Does a pages URL change with AJAX?

Tags: ajax, accessibility

I'm taking an online course from a site that does not provide for asking questions about the content, so I am asking you.

This is one of the MUSTS for page titles:
"On a so-called single-page application — in which AJAX is used to bring in new content without refreshing or loading the entire web page — any time that the URL changes, the page title should be updated accordingly"

I always thought that if you used ajax to change part of a page the page itself would remain static. That is why would a URL change with an AJAX call. Are there any examples showing what this looks like?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests don’t change the browser URL or history. To mimic the behaviour of traditional websites, single page apps will modify the URL and history and use the URL to change the view.

For more on changing the browser history, see [Adding and modifying History entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).